# iframe API continues sending 'postMessage' after iframe src changes

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I have an iframe that is implementing the youtube iframe api.  Once I change that iframe src to another video src (non-youtube), the api continues firing postMessage requests to the new origin infinitely.

I've narrowed it down to this chunk of code:

```
g.C = function(a) {
    a.id = this.g;
    a.channel = "widget";
    a = ab(a);
    var b = this.b;
    var c = jb(this.a.src);
    b = 0 == c.indexOf("https:") ? [c] : b.b ? [c.replace("http:", "https:")] : b.f ? [c] : [c, c.replace("http:", "https:")];
    if (!this.a.contentWindow) throw Error("The YouTube player is not attached to the DOM.");
    for (c = 0; c < b.length; c++) try {
        this.a.contentWindow.postMessage(a, b[c])
    } catch (d) {
        if (d.name && "SyntaxError" == d.name) ob(d, "WARNING");
        else throw d;
    } };
```

That continuously sends `this.a.contentWindow.postMessage(a, b[c])` without checking the destination of the contentWindow.

Is there a way to destroy the player once it is no longer needed so this postMessage will not be sent to other sources?

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 0):

There is method called player.destroy()
It is documented here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Accessing_and_Modifying_DOM_Nodes